# "Saw me in the subway," vs "saw me on the subway."

Tags: word-choice

What's the different between the two?

Example sentences:

> I saw you **in** the subway. You were following me.
>
> I saw you **on** the subway. You were following me.

Comment: Answered definitively (including mentioning the US - UK difference in usage) by CJ at [Englishforums.com](https://www.englishforums.com/English/OnTheSubwayOrInTheSubway/pdhcl/post.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rarely if ever encountered the first case, but even so I automatically interpret it to mean "I saw you in the subway station".  Your mileage may vary.  However, the second case unambiguously means "I saw you on the subway train."

Comment: Hello, endemic. I've close-voted the question for lack of signs of research (I rapidly found the link I've posted) (though California Jim may not be held in the esteem he deserves by some). But answers on ELU are also expected to contain supporting evidence, rather than just consist of what may be personal misconceptions / preferences (though I'm not saying your answer here is incorrect for the US usage).

Comment: That is fair! Though while we're both on a site about the use of the English language, I feel obliged to point out that the help article on [How do I write a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) uses the word "encouraged" in favor of "expected" :P  In lieu I tried to make it fairly clear what in my answer was speculation, in case future comers would improve upon it.  I agree that the context of US v UK English was important and missing, though.

Comment: Some contributors encourage the reasonable addition of supporting articles etc by downvoting answers lacking such.